# Clicking on an image in a listView and making it appear in a pictureBox

Tags: c#, image, listview, picturebox, imagelist

I have successfully imported and displayed horizontaly in a listView all the images from a folder/directory and now I want to be able to click on one of them and display that image in a big pictureBox above it called "mainPictureBox". I think I am close to that result, however what i have managed is to make the 100x100pixel image appear on the mainPictureBox that I clicked on from the listview rather than the high quality .PNG or .JPG from the folder. I'm guessing I need to use ImageKey or IndexKey or somehow associate the names of the images in the folder with the index of the clicked-on listView item. I am attaching an image of the GUI and the piece of code used for the imageList and listView if that helps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCXio.jpg       <---GUI screenshot

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\PhotoEditorProject\bin\Debug\Images");
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = i;
            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

my dear friend try this..

```
 int b = 0;
    public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        for (int z = 0; z < ofd.FileNames.Length; z++)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileNames[z]);
            string a = b.ToString();
            imageList1.Images.Add(a, img);
            var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add(ofd.FileName );
            listViewItem.ImageKey = a;
            b++;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s= listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
       Bitmap bm= new Bitmap (@"" +s);
       pictureBox1.Image = bm;
    }
```